# how can i link digitalocean, namecheap and send grid for sending mail, here is my current domain and dns config

Tags: sendmail, digital-ocean, sendgrid

i am trying to using sendgrid to sending mail. i have a domain server and previously connect with digitalocean droplet like image below. but when i try to auth my domain server with sendgrid and receive the msg below.

[namecheap config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDVeM.png)

[sendgrid error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pjgbc.png)

[digital ocean config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpBbJ.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need not to have `voidbraw.com` at the end of any of the three hostnames.

e.g.

hostname 1 should be `em1727`
hostname 2 should be `s1._domainkey`
hostname 3 should be `s2._domainkey`

Once you remove it, then try verifying from sendgrid.

Note: It might take some time for records to start functioning.

Comment: I just did what u did. For some reason it still displayed error messages for 2 out of 3 records, but I gave it a minute without changing anything and verified again and it worked, so thanks!

Comment: Thank you mate. I had this issue for a while, and it drove me crazy for years not having the domain validated. Thanks once again mate.

Comment: I had the same issue, worked for me too! Thanks so much!